# ADA compliancy questions regarding radio buttons and subordinate controls

Tags: html, web, radio-button, html-select

I have some ADA questions! First, can a radio button with a subordinate control, say a select box be ADA compliant?  If so, how does one provide meaningful labeling that isn't confusing to the user?  Could I do a visible label for the radio button and a hidden label for the the drop down box to enforce ADA and keep a non-confusing structure for the non-disabled users?

Comment: ADA - the disabilities act

Comment: There is a UX StackExchange site where this might be more on-topic